# I just want to print the key, not their index

Tags: python

I need to print the keys + their values and it always prints the index of the key too, how can I fix that?

```py
def task_3_4(something:str): 

    alphabet =list(string.ascii_letters)
    i = 0
    k=0
    while  i < len(alphabet):
        dicts = {alphabet[i]: 0}
        count = something.count(alphabet[i])
        dicts[i] = count
        if 0 < count:
            for k in dicts:
                print(k) 

        i = i+1
```

Comment: Do you know you're destroying and creating your `dicts` var every loop? And that it only ever has **one letter** in it at a time?

Comment: seems like an anti-pattern using a while loop with `i=i+1` instead of a `for char in alphabet` or `for i, char in enumerate(alphabet)`.

Comment: what is your sample input and expected output?

Comment: In addition to what @SyntaxVoid said, `dicts[i] = count` would create a new item in `dict` with the value of `i` as the key and `count` as the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code it seems like you are trying to do some sort of counter of different characters in the string?

There is no index. your "index" is the "i" iterator you are using for your while loop. This simply makes a new key in dicts as called by dicts[i]. Thus when you call the print loop, it just iterates through and reads out I as well.

Try:

```
dicts[alphabet[i]] = count
```

Also your print function only prints out the key of the dict entry instead of the key-value pair. to do that you can try:

```
for k in dicts:
    print(k,dicts[k])
```

Try reading up on the python docs for dicts.

> https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: i thought, i could overwrite the value by ' dicts[i] = count', but i already solved the problem by recognizing that this don't work! Thanks